# Pairwise distance between all centroid coordinate combinations - Matlab

Tags: matlab

[image]The script below label objects in an image based on their centroids. How can I preform a pairwise distance between all the centroid coordinate combinations (without overlapping) and return the results in a table? I was thinking about using pdist2 but I do not know how to construct the for loop.

Thanks.

Script:

```
clc;
clear all;
I = imread('E:/Elli.png');
imshow(I);
BW  =imbinarize(I);
BW = imfill(BW, 'holes');
BW = bwlabel(BW); 

s = regionprops(BW,'Area', 'BoundingBox', 'Eccentricity', 'MajorAxisLength', 'MinorAxisLength', 'Orientation', 'Perimeter','Centroid');


imshow(BW)
hold on
for k = 1:numel(s)
    c = s(k).Centroid;
    text(c(1), c(2), sprintf('%d', k), 'HorizontalAlignment', 'center', 'VerticalAlignment', 'middle');
end
hold off
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using `pdist2`, which finds the distances between points in two lists, use [`pdist`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html?s_tid=doc_ta). `pdist` takes all of the points in a single list and finds the distance between each pair.

In your example, `s.Centroid` gives a comma-separated list of points, so we need to coerce it into an array of points using [`vertcat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html?s_tid=doc_ta):

```
point_list = vertcat(s.Centroid);
```

Now we can feed this list to `pdist`:

```
dist_list = pdist(point_list);
```

`pdist` returns a list of distances from centroid `i` to centroid `j` such that `i < j`:

```
{1->2}, {1->3}, {1->4}, ... {1->n}, {2->3}, {2->4}, ..., {2->n}, {3->4}, etc.
```

In your example with 28 centroids, this will give you a total of 378 distances.

If you want that in a matrix form instead where element `(i,j)` is the distance from centroid `i` to centroid `j`, you can use [`squareform`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/squareform.html):

```
dist_mat = squareform(dist_list);
```

For 28 centroids, this will give you the full 28x28 matrix of distances.